# Is there a way to specify one provider for multiple scripts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I am setting up a basic provisioning script for multiple services in aws. I want to keep each section separate. So currently I have one directory in my repo for setting up the vpc and networking aspects in a folder called `vpc`

I was wondering if there is a way to use one `provider.tf` file in the root of the repo. That way when I eventually create another resource group I want to create ( for example an EC2 instance and its security groups + EBS etc ) I can create another directory in my repo and source one `provider.tf` file.

So my directory structure would look like

```
/myrepo/
|
 - provider.tf
|
 - vpc/
   |
    - vpc.tf
|
 - EC2/
   | 
    - ec2.tf
```

Comment: This is the default behavior.

Comment: Terraform will figure out for you automatically what provider is needed for the resources that you need to create and download the appropriate plugins when you run `terraform init`